# Inkscape missing pixels when upscaling svg

Tags: inkscape

I'm using inkscape 0.92.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

I'm using the command line to produce a jpg with a 4000 pixels width:

```
inkscape -z -f in.svg -j -w 4000 -e out.jpg
```

My problem is that when I zoom on the output, I can see that some pixels are "missing" (black color):

[image]

Why is that and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Please share the SVG file and let us know which region you're zooming in to if you want to know the cause.

Answer (score 0):

These missing pixels represent the background. Black is the default color.

To change the background color, use the -b option

inkscape -z -f in.svg -b white -w 4000 -e out.jpg